# OpenCV - How to capture two video feeds from same source - Python

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter, raspberry-pi, queue

I have a program where I need tkinter to display the feed from the Pi camera and I also need it to decode a QR code when it goes into the frame. I keep getting an error: `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object` because that second function cannot access the camera feed.

I have tried making frame a global variable, but that didn't seem to work either.

Any ideas on how to address this?

```
# import all the necessary modules
from tkinter import *
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from queue import Empty  # for excepting a specific error

import cv2
import pyzbar.pyzbar as pyzbar
import sys
import os
import requests
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import time

def resetGUI():
   root.configure(bg='white')
   nameFrame.configure(bg='white')
   instructionsFrame.configure(bg='white')
   nameLabel.config(text="", bg='white')
   instructionsLabel.config(text="Place your QR code under the scanner below.", bg='white')

def processScan(code):
   if code != "":
         print (code)
         #some post request
         return ["hellllllo"]

def showVideo():
   _, frame = vid.read()
   frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
   cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
   img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
   imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
   lmain.imgtk = imgtk
   lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
   cv2.waitKey(5)
   cv2.destroyAllWindows
   lmain.after(10, showVideo)

# this is the function that will be run in a child process
def startScanning(queue_):
   i = 0
   while i<2:
      # _,f = vid.read()
       _,frame = vid.read()
       decoded = pyzbar.decode(frame)
       for obj in decoded:
           queue_.put(obj.data)
           print('decoded')
       #cv2.imshow('QRCode',f)
       #cv2.waitKey(5)
       #cv2.destroyAllWindows
       #time.sleep(1)


# just a function to not write a `lambda`, just easier
# to read code
def start_process():
    Process(target=startScanning, args=(queue, ), daemon=True).start()


def updateGUI():
   try:
      data = queue.get(block=False)
      while not queue.empty():
         queue.get()
   except Empty:
      pass
   else:
      #queue.clear()
      code = processScan(data)
      if code:
         if len(code) > 1: #Pass ACCEPTED
            root.configure(bg='green'): #Pass DENIED
         root.after(3000, resetGUI)
   finally:
      root.after(100, updateGUI)


# crucial part is to use this if statement because
# child processes run this whole script again
if __name__ == '__main__':
   root = Tk()

   logo     = "logo.png"
   settings = "settings.png"

   if os.environ.get('DISPLAY','') == '':
     print('no display found. Using :0.0')
     os.environ.__setitem__('DISPLAY', ':0.0')


   #create main window
   #root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
   root.title("Title")
   root.geometry("480x800")
   root.configure(bg='white')
   ttelogo = PhotoImage(file = logo)
   settingslogo = PhotoImage(file = settings)

   #settings button
   settingsFrame = Frame(root,width=50,height=50,bg="white")
   settingsFrame.pack_propagate(0) # Stops child widgets of label_frame from resizing it
   settingsBtn = Button(settingsFrame, image=settingslogo).pack()
   settingsFrame.place(x=430,y=0)

   #logo
   img = Label(root, image=ttelogo, bg='white')
   img.image = ttelogo
   img.place(x=176.5,y=10)

   #Name Label
   nameFrame = Frame(root,width=400,height=100,bg="white")
   nameFrame.pack_propagate(0) # Stops child widgets of label_frame from resizing it
   nameLabel = Label(nameFrame,bg="white",fg="black",text="",font=("Calibri",22))
   nameLabel.pack()
   nameFrame.place(x=40,y=140)

   #Instructions Label
   instructionsFrame = Frame(root,width=440,height=100,bg="white")
   instructionsFrame.pack_propagate(0) # Stops child widgets of label_frame from resizing it
   instructionsLabel = Label(instructionsFrame,bg="white",fg="black",text="Hello",font=("Calibri",15))
   instructionsLabel.pack()
   instructionsFrame.place(x=20,y=210)

   #Camera Window
   cameraFrame = Frame(root, width=440, height=480)
   cameraFrame.place(x=20, y=260)

   #Camera Feed
   lmain = Label(cameraFrame)
   lmain.place(x=0, y=0)

   vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

   # define queue (since it is a global variable now
   # it can be easily used in the functions)
   queue = Queue()

   #label = Label(root)
   #label.pack()

   # initially start the update function
   updateGUI()

   # just a button for starting the process, but you can also simply
   # call the function
   start_process()

   showVideo()
   root.mainloop()
```

EDIT: with Threading & unnecessary code removed

```
# import all the necessary modules
from tkinter import *
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from queue import Empty  # for excepting a specific error

import cv2
import pyzbar.pyzbar as pyzbar
import sys
import os
import requests
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import time
import threading

def resetGUI():
   root.configure(bg='white')
   nameFrame.configure(bg='white')
   instructionsFrame.configure(bg='white')
   nameLabel.config(text="", bg='white')
   instructionsLabel.config(text="Place your QR code under the scanner below.", bg='white')

def processScan(code):
   if code != "":
         print (code)
         #some post request
         return ["hellllllo"]

def showVideo():
   vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
   _, frame = vid.read()
   frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
   cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
   img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
   imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
   lmain.imgtk = imgtk
   lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
   cv2.waitKey(5)
   cv2.destroyAllWindows
   lmain.after(10, showVideo)

# this is the function that will be run in a child process
def startScanning(queue_):
   i = 0
   while i<2:
      vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
      # _,f = vid.read()
       _,frame = vid.read()
       decoded = pyzbar.decode(frame)
       for obj in decoded:
           queue_.put(obj.data)
           print('decoded')

def start_process():
    threading.Thread(target=startScanning, args=(queue, ), daemon=True).start()


def updateGUI():
   try:
      data = queue.get(block=False)
      while not queue.empty():
         queue.get()
   except Empty:
      pass
   else:
      #queue.clear()
      code = processScan(data)
      if code:
         if len(code) > 1: #Pass ACCEPTED
            root.configure(bg='green'): #Pass DENIED
         root.after(3000, resetGUI)
   finally:
      root.after(100, updateGUI)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   root = Tk()

   logo     = "logo.png"
   settings = "settings.png"

   if os.environ.get('DISPLAY','') == '':
     print('no display found. Using :0.0')
     os.environ.__setitem__('DISPLAY', ':0.0')

   #create main window
   #root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
   root.title("Title")
   root.geometry("480x800")
   root.configure(bg='white')

   #Camera Window
   cameraFrame = Frame(root, width=440, height=480)
   cameraFrame.place(x=20, y=260)

   #Camera Feed
   lmain = Label(cameraFrame)
   lmain.place(x=0, y=0)

   queue = Queue()

   # initially start the update function
   updateGUI()

   start_process()

   showVideo()
   root.mainloop()
```

EDIT 2: Tried global vid

```
from tkinter import *
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from queue import Empty  # for excepting a specific error

import cv2
import pyzbar.pyzbar as pyzbar
import sys
import os
import requests
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import time
import threading

def resetGUI():
   root.configure(bg='white')
   nameFrame.configure(bg='white')
   instructionsFrame.configure(bg='white')
   nameLabel.config(text="", bg='white')
   instructionsLabel.config(text="Place your QR code under the scanner below.", bg='white')

def processScan(code):
   if code != "":
         print (code)
         #some post request
         return ["hellllllo"]

def showVideo():
   global vid
   vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
   _, frame = vid.read()
   frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
   cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
   img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
   imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
   lmain.imgtk = imgtk
   lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
   cv2.waitKey(5)
   cv2.destroyAllWindows
   lmain.after(10, showVideo)

# this is the function that will be run in a child process
def startScanning(queue_):
   i = 0
   while i<2:
      # _,f = vid.read()
       _,frame = vid.read()
       decoded = pyzbar.decode(frame)
       for obj in decoded:
           queue_.put(obj.data)
           print('decoded')

def start_process():
    threading.Thread(target=startScanning, args=(queue, ), daemon=True).start()


def updateGUI():
   try:
      data = queue.get(block=False)
      while not queue.empty():
         queue.get()
   except Empty:
      pass
   else:
      #queue.clear()
      code = processScan(data)
      if code:
         if len(code) > 1: #Pass ACCEPTED
            root.configure(bg='green'): #Pass DENIED
         root.after(3000, resetGUI)
   finally:
      root.after(100, updateGUI)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   root = Tk()

   logo     = "logo.png"
   settings = "settings.png"

   if os.environ.get('DISPLAY','') == '':
     print('no display found. Using :0.0')
     os.environ.__setitem__('DISPLAY', ':0.0')

   #create main window
   #root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
   root.title("Title")
   root.geometry("480x800")
   root.configure(bg='white')

   #Camera Window
   cameraFrame = Frame(root, width=440, height=480)
   cameraFrame.place(x=20, y=260)

   #Camera Feed
   lmain = Label(cameraFrame)
   lmain.place(x=0, y=0)

   queue = Queue()

   # initially start the update function
   updateGUI()

   showVideo()

   start_process()

   root.mainloop()
```

After latest update, this is the error:

```
[ WARN:0] global /root/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (890) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by index
Exception in Tkinter callback
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "stackoverflow2.py", line 49, in startScanning
    decoded = pyzbar.decode(frame)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyzbar/pyzbar.py", line 181, in decode
    pixels, width, height = _pixel_data(image)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyzbar/pyzbar.py", line 147, in _pixel_data
    pixels, width, height = image
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 749, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "stackoverflow2.py", line 34, in showVideo
    cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3) /root/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'
```

Comment: Why are you using `multiprocessing`? It will be much easier if you just used `threading`. Right now `startScanning` expects to be able to access the global variable `vid` but `vid` was defined in another process. That can get quite messy. Instead of `Process(...)` use `threading.Thread(...)` (after you `import threading`)

Comment: Paste the full traceback and remove the unnecessary codes.

Comment: @TheLizzard I just updated the question. Is that what you mean? I am getting some threading errors: ```[ WARN:0] global /root/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (802) requestBuffers VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): failed VIDIOC_REQBUFS: errno=16 (Device or resource busy)```

Comment: Try adding `global vid` to `showVideo` and remove the `vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` from `startScanning`. That way you only have 1 video capture

Comment: @TheLizzard when startScanning() is now called I get a ```NameError: name 'vid' is not defined``` and also ```[ WARN:0] global /root/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (890) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by index``` I will update the question to show.

Comment: Try swapping `start_process()` and the `showVideo()`. Right now `showVideo` defines a global variable `vid` that `startScanning` needs.

Comment: @TheLizzard good catch. Still getting another error about not being able to access the feed. Question was updated.

Comment: @ToddMurphy Now it looks like the problem is that the `.read()` returns an empty image. Given the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a473055e77dd7faa4d26d686226b292c1), I would guess that there is something else going on. Also another small note (not related), you used `cv2.destroyAllWindows` and not `cv2.destroyAllWindows()`.

Comment: Why not just combine your 2 scripts? ie: `do_something() if qr_code else display_gui()`

Comment: Why don't you call `pyzbar.decode(frame)` inside `showVideo()`?